how do you "SAVE AS"?
I am on Mac OS 12.4, I make a new file in textedit, I save it and give it a name...
I slightly modify the contents-- and I want to keep the original, but have a variation..  I click File to choose "Save as"... AND THERE IS NO SAVE AS (anymore)!
...  I click the name of the file at the top of the window, thinking this will do what I want, but NO it just renames it.
So, WHERE did Apple put SAVE AS?

Send us a flag if option and the accepted answer to make a shortcut to expose this explicitly in the file menu doesn’t work great for you. We can reopen this if you need a different fix. Help menu should expose this in each app as well…
